# InternetAccess with Jetty and a Webserver. Client-Server Communication 2 machines, computer, java

Tags: java, request, webserver, jetty

I need some advice in the following matter:

I have two machines that are connected via ethernet. 
One machine (lets call it ServerSide) is also connected to the Internet via LAN. The second machine (ClientSide) is offline, in the beginning.

So ServerSide is creating a webserver with Jetty on port XY. ClientSide opens a webbrowser and requests some page (e.g. stackoverflow.com). The request will be forwarded to port XY and the webserver. ServerSide would have to send the request to the internet and then back over ServerSide to ClientSide, so the webbrowser should display the requested webpage.

Is it even possible to do that this way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need a [web proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Web_proxy_servers) ?

Comment: Do you want to program a web proxy or do you just want to use one? For me it' sounds like he want's to develop his own proxy. The answer is in both cases: Yes. You could that. I recommend then to search how a usual HTTP proxy works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What you need on server side is an HTTP Proxy and there are plenty of existing solutions in the market.
Check out the [Wikipedia article about proxies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server). Bear in mind that the client might require some configuration (Proxy settings) so that it forwards the requests to the proxy rather than attempting to reach the final host.